# Coordinates in General relativity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I've begun studying basics of general relativity and I've a doubt regarding coordinates.

In GR coordinates are a set of numbers which label points in spacetime.
Can I set up three mutually perpendicular meter rods and a clock and use them as coordinates $(t, x, y, z)$ in curved spacetime?

Can I do it in flat Minkowski space?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/733848/